# Android Spinner with many items?

Tags: android, lists, drop-down-list, spinner

I am looking for the best way to let the user choose one option from a list that might be somewhat long.

I was considering an AutoCompleteTextView, but it is important that the user only can choose between items from the list, not input their own. For this I would normally use a Spinner, but the number of items available for this selection might get rather large over time, thus it would be nice if the users could filter or search the items.

I would prefer to have a solution that will, when not activated, fit on a single line. This is for other design reasons (this happens in a dialog).

What should I do?

I so far have two possible solutions:

1) AutoCompleteTextView. I will then warn the user that the "selected" item isn't valid if the content of the field is not one of the items.
User pros: Can enter text and have results filtered. Will not get frustrated by having to scroll through many items.

2) Spinner. Was designed to handle selection between items on a list. User pros: Will be forced to select only between valid options, won't be confronted with error message.

Maybe someone has a better idea or know of a way to combine the pros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use AutoCompleteTextView entries only

If you have too much entries for a spinner, this is the best known way currently.

[image: typeahead]
[image: typeahead no results]

An implementation solution is on [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394054/android-restrict-user-to-select-from-autocompletion-textview-only)

Comment: Yes, this is the kind of solution I was thinking about, thank you.

Comment: Btw: be aware that users need to know what they are searching for.

Comment: They will be ^^ They will be searching for customer names from their own database of customers.